# How to connect to a ssl vpn tunnel with motp(Mobile One Time Password) using Ubuntu(16.04.1)?

Tags: 16.04, vpn, openvpn, ssl

The company decided that they needed more security regarding VPN, and they changed some things to the vpn. Which is fine, but I don't know how to connect to a ssl vpn tunnel with motp(Mobile One Time Password) using Ubuntu(16.04.1)?

Any ideas how?

Found out other or Windows use DrayTekVPN, which is not available for Linux...

Already installed the following packages

```
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-vpnc
```